# Check if elements in numpy array are between columns of a 2-column numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I have a 1-D numpy array `a` with arbitrary size `N`, and I have other numpy array `b` with exactly 2 columns and `M` rows. I want to build a 2-D array with shape `(M, N)` where the `(i,j)` element is the `bool` value `b[:,0][i] <= a[j] <= b[:,1][i]`. I want a solution that does not go through a for loop.

Example:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([10,  2,  5])

b = np.array([[ 0,  5],[ 5, 10]])


# Expected array

np.array([[False, True, True], [True, False, True]])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most direct way is to add an axis and broadcast:

```
(b[:,0][:, np.newaxis] <= a) & (a <= b[:,1][:, np.newaxis])
```

You can think of the broadcasting in terms of a nested for-loop. You want an output with shape `(M,N)`, you have `a` with shape `(N,)` (`for j in range(N):`) and `b[:,0]`/`b[:,1]` with shape `(M,)` (`for i in range(M):`). So you would want to cast `b[:,0]`/`b[:,1]` to shape `(M,1)` for another level to the for-loop.

```
M x 1  for i in range(M):
    N      for j in range(N):
-----
M x N          answer[i,j] = ...
```